# Diameter of a set.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A$ is a nonempty set in a metric space $(X, d)$. Define

$$ \delta(A) = \sup_{x,y \in A} d(x,y) $$

Is it true that if $A \subseteq B$, then $\delta(A) \leq \delta(B) $??

Comment: Yes, you can prove it by contradiction.

Comment: You can also prove it directly.

Comment: There's really no need for contradiction: You're taking the supremum over a smaller set, so you don't get a larger result.

Comment: I am having difficulty proving the answer is yes. Any help? thanks

Comment: Beauty contest principle:  IF you are sup-ing over a larger set, the sup gets bigger. If you are inf-ing over a larger set, the inf gets smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of the supremum: It's the least upper bound on a set of real numbers. Now if $C \subseteq D$ are sets of real numbers, every upper bound on $D$ is an upper bound on $C$; this proves that $\sup C \le \sup D$.

Finally, since $A \subseteq B$, it's immediate that

$$\{d(x, y) : x, y \in A\} \subseteq \{d(x, y) : x, y \in B\}$$

and by applying the previous paragraph, we're done.

Comment: thank you very much for your time!!